# apache http client: request does not get redirected

Tags: java, http

I need to check this scenario: When I access a URL, it should be redirected to a new URL, curl is good:

```
curl -i http://localhost:8080/index.html
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Fri, 04 Oct 2019 18:57:07 GMT
Location: http://localhost:8080/
Content-Length: 0
```

I get the 302 status code as expected. But when I try to run this using apache http client in Java, I get the status code 200 instead. Java code:

```
HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://localhost:8080/index.html");
HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
System.out.println("Completed executing the request, status: " + response.getStatusLine());
Assert.assertEquals(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode(), 200);
```

How can I also get the 302 status code in JAVA ?

Comment: I think you are getting the 302 redirect from the server, but the http client code 'hides' that fact, follows the redirect automajically and then returns the page represented in the location attribute.  If you must see the redirect see @bhusak's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to disable redirects. Try this:

```
HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
params.setParameter("http.protocol.handle-redirects",false);
HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://localhost:8080/index.html");
request.setParams(params);
```